# Адаптировать обьекты css

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 графика ,под каждый графиком есть datepicker где можно задавать дату и возле одного графика должны быть маркеры (рис 1 ) Как это сделать чтоб когда разрешение экрана меняется то одно на другое не налазило ? Можно это на моем примере показать ,очень прошу.

**HTML 2 графика**

```
    <div class="main-flex-container">
   <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-item1">
              <a href="chart_diagramms_average_new.php"  class="hbut3">СРЕДНЕЕ</a>
              <a href="chart_new.php?number=21"  class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

                  <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 1-->
             <div id="gistorgam1" style="min-width: 300px; min-height: auto;  margin-top:-170px;text-align:center;"></div>

                  <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 1-->
             <div id="horizontal1" style="min-width: 300px; height: 80px;  margin-top:-15px;"></div>

            </div>
        <!--END-->

            <div class="flex-item2">
            <a href="chart_diagramms_average_new.php"  class="hbut4">СРЕДНЕЕ</a>
            <a href="chart_new.php?number=24"  class="hbut2">ГРАФИК</a>
                  <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 2-->
             <div id="gistorgam2" style="min-width: 300px; min-height: auto; margin-top:-120px;text-align:center;"></div>

                  <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 2-->
             <div id="horizontal2" style="min-width: 300px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

 </div>
```

**МАРКЕРЫ ПО ЛЕВУЮ СТОРОНУ ОТ ГРАФИКА**

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #4b0e0e;">ЧО-1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #0b4a0d;">ЧО-2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #1c165f;">ЧО-3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background:  yellow;">ЧО-4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #ff0000;">ЧО-5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #00fff5;">ЧО-6</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS ГРАФИКОВ**

```
.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  min-height: 500px; 

}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.column-reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.column-reverse1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;


}


.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;

}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    align-content:space-around;

}

.column-reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    align-content:space-around;

}
.column-reverse1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    align-content:space-around;

}
.flex-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 0px;
  /*background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0);*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
    align-content:space-around;
}

.column-reverse {
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 0px;
 /* background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0);*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
    align-content:space-around;
}
.column-reverse1 {
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 0px;
 /* background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0);*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
    align-content:space-around; 

}

.flex-item1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px ;
  min-height: 60px;
  padding-top: 160px ;
 /* background: rgba(175, 175, 175, 0);*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px solid;
    align-content:space-around;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81);
}
```

**CSS МАРКЕРОВ**

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

row {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**РИС.1**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте оттолкнуться от единиц [vh, vw, vmin, vmax](https://html5book.ru/edinicy-izmereniya-vh-vw-vmin-vmax/), они вычисляются относительно размеров окна браузера.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать это на моем примере ? Я понял о чем вы говорите,но я ранее использовал тоже эти форматы "vh,vw..." но все равно скачет